# Getting Template::Error (Undefined method 'each') for nil:NIL Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

View:-

```
  <% @dating_advices.each do |da| %>
   <% if da['is-displayed'][0]['content'] == 'true' %>
   <div class="dating_advice">
      <h4><%= da['title'][0] %></h4>
      <p><b><%= da['author'][0] %></b></p>
      <p><%= da['content'] %></p>
   </div>
   <hr>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Controller:-

```
def dating_advices
@current_menu = "MatchMasters"
logger.debug "*** Current site id: #{@current_site.id}"
#@hide_quick_search = true

@passed_args = {
    'event_action' => 'ws',
    'site_id' => @current_site.site_id
}
result = call_dating_advices_ws(@passed_args)
if result && result['errorcode'][0] == 'success'
  @dating_advices = result['payload'][0]['payload']
 end
end
```

Now when I click on dating advices on my webpage it gives an error"Getting Template::Error (Undefined method 'each') for nil:NIL Class"

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't get any `@dating_advices` -- which would mean you're calling each on an instance var that doesn't exist.

The way your controller is written, `@dating_advices` is never defined if the result variable is not defined.

You could quickly patch it with a `@dataing_advices = []` (or a hash -- anything with an .each method) and figure out why your controller is failing.

You could do something like

```
if result && result['errorcode'][0] == 'success'
   ... your dating advice code
else
   raise result
   (or @dating_advice = {})
end
```

basically you need to always defined `@dating_advice` OR you need to handle that value not being defined in your view.